# Functional component and return statement in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting a weird error of unreachable code detected in the return statement of ReactJS.

In the code snippet given below, the error is shown at the div with the button component.

How can I resolve this issue?

```
function RenderComments({ comments }) {
    return (
        comments.map((comment) =>
            <div>
                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                    <li className='font-quote'>{comment.comment}</li>
                </ul>
                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                    <li className='font-author'>--{comment.author}, {comment.date}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
        <div className = "row m-1" >
            <Button type="submit" value="submit"><i className="fa fa-pencil"></i> Submit Comment</Button>
        </div>   
    );
}
```

Comment: That's an invalid code... You're out of the return statement you're using `row m-1`. Kindly check my answer for a working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an invalid code... You're out of the return statement you're using `row m-1`.

You need to use `<></>` fragments to return two or more elements:

```js
function RenderComments({ comments }) {
  return (
    <>
      {comments.map((comment) => (
        <div>
          <ul className="list-unstyled">
            <li className="font-quote">{comment.comment}</li>
          </ul>
          <ul className="list-unstyled">
            <li className="font-author">
              --{comment.author}, {comment.date}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}

      <div className="row m-1">
        <Button type="submit" value="submit">
          <i className="fa fa-pencil"></i> Submit Comment
        </Button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: How am I returning two or more elements?

Comment: @Nimrod After the `return ( .... )` you have another `<div className="row m-1">`, that's why. :)

Answer (score 2):

The div containing the Button is not reachable, you should  wrap both in a grouping tag, a fragment for example:

```
function RenderComments({ comments }) {
  return (
    <>
      {comments.map((comment) => (
        <div>
          <ul className="list-unstyled">
            <li className="font-quote">{comment.comment}</li>
          </ul>
          <ul className="list-unstyled">
            <li className="font-author">
              --{comment.author}, {comment.date}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className="row m-1">
        <Button type="submit" value="submit">
          <i className="fa fa-pencil"></i> Submit Comment
        </Button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function RenderComments({ comments }) {
  return (
    <>
      {comments.map((comment) => (
        <div>
          <ul className="list-unstyled">
            <li className="font-quote">{comment.comment}</li>
          </ul>
          <ul className="list-unstyled">
            <li className="font-author">
              --{comment.author}, {comment.date}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}

      <div className="row m-1">
        <Button type="submit" value="submit">
          <i className="fa fa-pencil"></i> Submit Comment
        </Button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```